# Running bash commands in Ansible task

Tags: python, mysql, ansible

I am porting a `Makefile` into a series of Ansible tasks.  The make file has these two lines of code which are troubling me when it comes to ansible:

```
SERVERS := shell mysql "select hostname from servers"
EASY_INSTALL := wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

Firstly,  what's the appropriate Ansible way to use dynamic `vars` for the value of SERVERS?  The value of servers will depends upon the environment, i.e. stage, production, etc.

Secondly, I don't want to install the python-setuptools package from `aptitude` because I have had nothing but problems with it in the past.  So how do I run a `wget` shell command with Ansible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to download a script and then run that as a command against a number of servers.

The concept of 'hosts' in an Ansible playbook covers your 'servers' concept - you would need to populate an inventory that Ansible can read for the hosts, or even possibly pass in the hosts as a variable when running the playbook (lets call that variable 'servers').

wget and running various commands are all standard Ansible modules (get_url is the generalised name for wget).

So, an example playbook:

```
- hosts: "{{ servers }}"
  tasks:
    - name: get a file
      get_url:
        url: "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py"
        dest: "/usr/ez_setup.py"

    - name: run a command
      command: "python /usr/ez_setup.py"
```

You would then call the above playbook (lets call it `shipit.yaml`) like this:

```
ansible-playbook /usr/shipit.yaml --extra-vars "servers=10.0.0.1"
```

You could also use the add_hosts module and a custom group name to dynamically read the servers from your database and then populate the custom group, then run your next set of commands against that custom group as the `hosts` item.

You milage may vary depending on if you need sudo enabled (`sudo: yes`) or not, and there may be a better way of running your python script than using command (command will run every time with no regard to if it has already been run - not idempotent in other words).

Hopefully the above gives you a good starting point.

Comment: that is a good start.  I think the add_hosts module is the better choice.  I need to verify it first, then will accept the answer

Comment: There's a syntax error on get_url.  It should be get_url: url=URL dest=PATH

Comment: So you're just running code from internet on your machine !